# Запрос с динамически формируемым количеством и содержимым колонок

Tags: mysql

Есть 4 таблицы
[image: schema]

[image: таблицы]

1. нужно вывести значения из таблицы `country`.
2. присоединить к ним все значения из таблицы `groups` (значение будет использоваться в виде имени колонки).
3. В этих колонках выводить через запятую значения из таблицы tags, если они есть.

**UPD**:
Получилось вывести только вот это:

```
SELECT country.id, country.name, GROUP_CONCAT(tags.name) AS result 
FROM country
LEFT JOIN tag_res ON tag_res.country=country.id 
LEFT JOIN tags ON tags.id=tag_res.tag 
LEFT JOIN groups ON groups.id=tags.group_id
GROUP BY country.name
```

Comment: А в чём вопрос/проблема?

Comment: ^ Основная и единственная проблема понятна - формирование списка колонок

Comment: [http://i003.radikal.ru/1509/c8/f7649d106b3a.png]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

решить задачу можно, например, с помощью вызова процедуры:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ce65/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
create table country (id int, name text)//
insert into country values (1, 'russia'), (2, 'italy'), (3, 'usa')//
create table tags (id int, name text, group_id int)//
insert into tags values(1,'lada',1),(2,'gmc',1),(3,'blue',2),
  (4,'red',2),(5,'niva',1)//
create table tag_res (tag int, country int)//
insert into tag_res values (1, 1), (2, 3), (5, 1), (4, 1), (3, 1), (3, 3)//
create table groups (id int, name text)//
insert into groups values (1, 'car brand'), (2, 'car color')//

create procedure s ()
begin
  declare bdone int;
  declare gid int;
  declare gname text;
  declare var1 text;
  declare var2 text;
  declare curs cursor for select id, name from groups;
  declare continue handler for not found set bdone = 1;
  set bdone = 0;
  set var1 = '';
  set var2 = '';
  open curs;
  fetch_loop: loop
    fetch curs into gid, gname;
    if bdone = 1 then leave fetch_loop; end if;
    set var1 = concat ( var1, 'left join tags t', gid, 
      ' on t', gid, '.group_id = ', gid, ' and t', gid, '.id = r.tag ');
    set var2 = concat ( var2, ', coalesce(group_concat(t', gid,
      '.name), "") as `', gname, '`');
  end loop;

  set @str = concat ('select c.id, c.name', var2, ' from country c ',
    'left join tag_res r on r.country = c.id ', var1, 'group by c.id');
  prepare stmt from @str;
  execute stmt;
  deallocate prepare stmt;

end//
```

**Query 1**:

```
call s()
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1ce65/1/0)**:

```
| id |   name | car brand | car color |
|----|--------|-----------|-----------|
|  1 | russia | lada,niva |  blue,red |
|  2 |  italy |           |           |
|  3 |    usa |       gmc |      blue |
```

Comment: Спасибо, за то что откликнулись, но хотелось бы без процедур решить задачу

Comment: @thetekst, средствами *mysql* это невозможно.